# How to find the area of a kite from a given area of triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

In a kite $AEDC$, the shaded area is known, and $EB \parallel DC$. It is also given that $3|AB|=4|BC|$. How can one find the area of the kite?

I have tried using similar triangles (drawing the diagonals $AD$ and $EC$), since the ratio between $AB$ and $BC$ is given, so I thought that's a hint, but I am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $EB \parallel DC$, we have $A(EBC) = A(EBD)$ (both triangles have base $EB$ and since $EB \parallel DC$, they have the same height for that base). Rest is just to use the given ratio.

[image]